# Parse DOM document to array php

Tags: php, dom, domxpath

*
What I want is, for the DOM to instead of printing the results line by line in a "foreach" loop, rather store it in an array.... So it should look like a list i.e.
"[0] 16GB USB Stick" "[1] Computer monitor" "[2] wireless keyboard"
etc etc
So far I have this, but it only stores the last value from the for each loop.. Please help!
*

```
$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHtmlFile('some online shop');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($html);
$nodelist = $xpath->query( "//div[@class='productname']/p" );

foreach ($nodelist as $n)
    {
        $value = $n->nodeValue;
        $list = array($value);
    }

echo $list[0];
```

Comment: You are overwriting the `$list` variable with every iteration of your `foreach` loop. You need to push a new element onto the end of an existing array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you're overriding it in each loop. Create an array, and add to that array:

```
$list = array();

foreach ($nodelist as $n)
{
    $value = $n->nodeValue;
    $list[] = $value;
}

// Check there's at least one item in the array before accessing it
if (count($list) > 0)
{
    echo $list[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into how arrays work in PHP. What you're doing wrong is you are re-declaring the array on each iteration, instead of adding more information to it.

```
$list = array();

foreach ($nodelist as $n) {
    $list[] = $n->nodeValue;
}

var_dump($list);
```

**Explanation:**

`[]` basically means - add an item in this array, and auto generate the key.

The foreach I wrote is equivalent to this one:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($nodelist as $n) {
    $list[$i] = $n->nodeValue;
    $i ++;
}
```